# Hibernate LoadContexts:122 - HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections)

Tags: java, hibernate

Lately I've been experiencing a rather "weird" (for lack of a better word) issue in Hibernate. When trying to persist my entity, the following WARN's / ERROR's get thrown:

```
WARN [quartzScheduler_Worker-2]         LoadContexts:122  - HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@4bf3ab85<rs=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl@1786369e>

WARN [quartzScheduler_Worker-2] CollectionLoadContext:351  - HHH000160: On CollectionLoadContext#cleanup, localLoadingCollectionKeys contained [1] entries

ERROR [quartzScheduler_Worker-2] AbstractArticleImportJob:288  - Failed to update article. 
org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [be.persgroep.red.mow.config.entities.hibernate.content.ArticleBlock#2349544]
```

Posting the rest of the stacktrace here below:

```
org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [be.persgroep.red.mow.config.entities.hibernate.content.ArticleBlock#2349544]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$1$1.handleEntityNotFound(SessionFactoryImpl.java:244) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:212) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:262) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1098) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1025) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:671) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:489) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:168) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1108) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:964) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:911) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:312) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2238) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:674) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1855) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:549) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:545) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.getElementsIterator(CollectionType.java:246) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.getElementsIterator(CollectionType.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction.getAllElementsIterator(CascadingAction.java:452) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction.access$100(CascadingAction.java:52) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$7.getCascadableChildrenIterator(CascadingAction.java:320) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:427) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:369) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:345) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:449) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.justCascade(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsPersistent(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:147) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:843) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:836) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$7.cascade(CascadingAction.java:315) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:399) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:342) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:429) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:369) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:345) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:449) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.justCascade(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsPersistent(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:147) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:843) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:836) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$7.cascade(CascadingAction.java:315) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:399) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:342) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:424) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.justCascade(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:190) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsPersistent(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:147) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:78) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:853) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:827) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:831) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
at be.persgroep.red.mow.config.dao.hibernate.BaseDaoImpl.persist(BaseDaoImpl.java:59) ~[config-3.11.jar:na]
at be.persgroep.red.mow.config.dao.hibernate.BaseDaoImpl.persist(BaseDaoImpl.java:25) ~[config-3.11.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor289.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260) ~[spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94) ~[spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy66.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at be.persgroep.red.mow.jobs.facade.ImportArticleFacadeImpl.createOrUpdateArticle(ImportArticleFacadeImpl.java:62) ~[classes:na]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor352.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260) ~[spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94) ~[spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.createOrUpdateArticle(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at be.persgroep.red.mow.jobs.qrtzjobs.article.AbstractArticleImportJob.createOrUpdateArticle(AbstractArticleImportJob.java:277) [classes:na]
at be.persgroep.red.mow.jobs.qrtzjobs.article.AbstractArticleImportJob.createOrUpdateArticleAndRelatedData(AbstractArticleImportJob.java:178) [classes:na]
at be.persgroep.red.mow.jobs.qrtzjobs.article.AbstractArticleImportJob.handleUpdateFeed(AbstractArticleImportJob.java:148) [classes:na]
at be.persgroep.red.mow.jobs.qrtzjobs.article.AbstractArticleImportJob.handleArticleUpdates(AbstractArticleImportJob.java:126) [classes:na]
at be.persgroep.red.mow.jobs.qrtzjobs.article.AbstractArticleImportJob.doExecute(AbstractArticleImportJob.java:113) [classes:na]
at be.persgroep.red.mow.jobs.qrtzjobs.AbstractImportJob.execute(AbstractImportJob.java:41) ~[classes:na]
at be.persgroep.red.mow.jobs.qrtzjobs.AbstractMowQuartzJob.executeInternal(AbstractMowQuartzJob.java:26) ~[classes:na]
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:113) ~[spring-context-support-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
```

I'm pretty baffled by the error to be honest. It's a rather huge application, and I have no clue how such an error comes into play. My guess is that Hibernate somehow feels the need to trigger the Collection cleanup, and that this causes issues when trying to persist the entity afterwards. The fail-safe cleanup warning however, is supposed to be a bug, fixed in Hibernate 3.2.5 (see https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2936 ). The Hibernate version used in my project is 4.2.7, so that shouldn't be the issue. I've found very little information so far on this issue, hence my question.
Do you guys have any suggestions on what to look for in my code that might eventually trigger this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding, the error is in `AbstractArticleImportJob` (and the error is that `ArticleBlock` with ID #2349544 doesn't exist), the 2 previous logs are just warnings. Can we see the code for `AbstractArticleImportJob`

Comment: ImportArticleFacadeImpl: Row 62: articleDao.persist(articleToUpdate);
Just "showing" the code is not quite gonna work, the whole transaction takes up about 20 classes. There's a whole lot of functionality going on before the article itself gets persisted to the database (updating fields and child elements)

Comment: As far as I can tell, the error gets thrown just when Hibernate tries to persist the article to the database. Every update on that particular article triggers the same stacktrace: It starts with those 2 warnings, and then crashes on the persist. So I'm strongly inclined to believe that the cleanup collections and "objectNotFoundException" are somehow related. Hence my question if I could get any pointers towards what might trigger this

Comment: I have this same problem and oddly the code generally works but sometimes it does not. No idea why