# HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

My issue seems to be similar to the below issue.

[Hibernate LoadContexts:122 - HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35415574/hibernate-loadcontexts122-hhh000100-fail-safe-cleanup-collections)

I went through a lot of Hibernate clean up issue reported on the web but did not get a satisfactory answer though. Can some help me find the route cause for that or with the resolution.

Error stack:

```
20:00:21,583 INFO  [org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener] (Camel (camelContext) thread #8 - JmsConsumer[Clinical%20Quality%20Measures%20Reporting1926768417751230.job.queue]) HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.gehcit.cp.chart.data.MedicationInfoData#187794]
20:00:21,599 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.LoadContexts] (Camel (camelContext) thread #8 - JmsConsumer[Clinical%20Quality%20Measures%20Reporting1926768417751230.job.queue]) HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@3975f4b5<rs=oracle.jdbc.driver.ForwardOnlyResultSet@4723c24d>
20:00:21,599 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext] (Camel (camelContext) thread #8 - JmsConsumer[Clinical%20Quality%20Measures%20Reporting1926768417751230.job.queue]) HHH000160: On CollectionLoadContext#cleanup, localLoadingCollectionKeys contained [576] entries
20:00:21,599 ERROR [org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect] (Camel (camelContext) thread #8 - JmsConsumer[Clinical%20Quality%20Measures%20Reporting1926768417751230.job.queue]) Application exception overridden by commit exception: com.gehcit.cp.cem.exception.IRRecoverableJobException: org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.gehcit.cp.chart.data.MedicationInfoData#187794]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cem.payloadgenerator.CcdaCcdPayloadGenerator.createCCD(CcdaCcdPayloadGenerator.java:125) [CommonEventModel.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3461]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cem.payloadgenerator.CcdaCcdPayloadGenerator.generatePayload_aroundBody12(CcdaCcdPayloadGenerator.java:87) [CommonEventModel.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3461]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cem.payloadgenerator.CcdaCcdPayloadGenerator$AjcClosure13.run(CcdaCcdPayloadGenerator.java:1) [CommonEventModel.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3461]
    at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149) [aspectjrt-1.8.9.jar:]
    at com.gehcit.cp.aop.monitor.MonitoredClassAspect.run(MonitoredClassAspect.java:53) [CentricityPracticeCore.jar:]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cem.payloadgenerator.CcdaCcdPayloadGenerator.generatePayload_aroundBody14(CcdaCcdPayloadGenerator.java:84) [CommonEventModel.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3461]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cem.payloadgenerator.CcdaCcdPayloadGenerator$AjcClosure15.run(CcdaCcdPayloadGenerator.java:1) [CommonEventModel.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3461]
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:66) [spring-aspects-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:72) [spring-aspects-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) [spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:70) [spring-aspects-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cem.payloadgenerator.CcdaCcdPayloadGenerator.generatePayload(CcdaCcdPayloadGenerator.java:84) [CommonEventModel.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3461]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cem.jobprocessing.CcdaCcdPayloadProcessor.fetchPayloadMessageFromJob(CcdaCcdPayloadProcessor.java:75) [CommonEventModel.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3461]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cem.jobprocessing.CcdaCcdPayloadProcessor.process(CcdaCcdPayloadProcessor.java:49) [CommonEventModel.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3461]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63) [camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77) [camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542) [camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:400) [camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:172) [camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120) [camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83) [camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:117) [camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77) [camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542) [camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:400) [camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:172) [camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542) [camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processByErrorHandler(TransactionErrorHandler.java:220) [camel-spring-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:101) [camel-spring-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:114) [camel-spring-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77) [camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542) [camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processByErrorHandler(TransactionErrorHandler.java:220) [camel-spring-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler$1.doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionErrorHandler.java:183) [camel-spring-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.doInTransaction(TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.java:34) [spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) [spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.doInTransactionTemplate(TransactionErrorHandler.java:176) [camel-spring-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processInTransaction(TransactionErrorHandler.java:136) [camel-spring-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:105) [camel-spring-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:114) [camel-spring-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197) [camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197) [camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97) [camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:112) [camel-jms-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:721) [spring-jms-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:681) [spring-jms-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:651) [spring-jms-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:317) [spring-jms-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:235) [spring-jms-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1166) [spring-jms-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1060) [spring-jms-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_102]
Caused by: org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.gehcit.cp.chart.data.MedicationInfoData#187794]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$1$1.handleEntityNotFound(SessionFactoryImpl.java:247) [hibernate-core-4.2.26.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.26.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.returnNarrowedProxy(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:295) [hibernate-core-4.2.26.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.26.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:256) [hibernate-core-4.2.26.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.26.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152) [hibernate-core-4.2.26.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.26.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1053) [hibernate-core-4.2.26.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.26.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:980) [hibernate-core-4.2.26.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.26.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:714) [hibernate-core-4.2.26.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.26.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:502) [hibernate-core-4.2.26.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.26.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:168) [hibernate-core-4.2.26.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.26.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:137) [hibernate-core-4.2.26.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.26.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1140) [hibernate-core-4.2.26.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.26.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:968) [hibernate-core-4.2.26.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.26.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:916) [hibernate-core-4.2.26.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.26.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:347) [hibernate-core-4.2.26.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.26.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2578) [hibernate-core-4.2.26.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.26.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2564) [hibernate-core-4.2.26.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.26.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2394) [hibernate-core-4.2.26.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.26.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2389) [hibernate-core-4.2.26.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.26.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:495) [hibernate-core-4.2.26.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.26.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:357) [hibernate-core-4.2.26.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.26.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:198) [hibernate-core-4.2.26.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.26.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1230) [hibernate-core-4.2.26.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.26.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101) [hibernate-core-4.2.26.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.26.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.gehcit.cp.chart.dao.impl.MedicationDAOImpl.findMedicationsByActiveSignedPatientAndInactiveSignedPatient(MedicationDAOImpl.java:602) [CentricityPractice.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3495]
    at com.gehcit.cp.chart.bo.impl.MedicationBOImpl.findMedicationsByPersonIDAndDocumentIDAndDataInclusionType_aroundBody8(MedicationBOImpl.java:126) [CentricityPractice.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3495]
    at com.gehcit.cp.chart.bo.impl.MedicationBOImpl$AjcClosure9.run(MedicationBOImpl.java:1) [CentricityPractice.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3495]
    at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149) [aspectjrt-1.8.9.jar:]
    at com.gehcit.cp.aop.monitor.MonitoredClassAspect.run(MonitoredClassAspect.java:53) [CentricityPracticeCore.jar:]
    at com.gehcit.cp.chart.bo.impl.MedicationBOImpl.findMedicationsByPersonIDAndDocumentIDAndDataInclusionType(MedicationBOImpl.java:103) [CentricityPractice.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3495]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cda.data.ClinicalDataRepositoryImpl.findMedications(ClinicalDataRepositoryImpl.java:1554) [CentricityPractice.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3495]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cda.builder.MedicationsBuilder.getMedicationList(MedicationsBuilder.java:1606) [CentricityPractice.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3495]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cda.builder.MedicationsBuilder.createSectionEntries_aroundBody4(MedicationsBuilder.java:206) [CentricityPractice.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3495]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cda.builder.MedicationsBuilder$AjcClosure5.run(MedicationsBuilder.java:1) [CentricityPractice.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3495]
    at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149) [aspectjrt-1.8.9.jar:]
    at com.gehcit.cp.aop.monitor.MonitoredAspect.run(MonitoredAspect.java:36) [CentricityPracticeCore.jar:]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cda.builder.MedicationsBuilder.createSectionEntries(MedicationsBuilder.java:203) [CentricityPractice.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3495]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cda.builder.MedicationsBuilder.buildSection_aroundBody0(MedicationsBuilder.java:166) [CentricityPractice.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3495]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cda.builder.MedicationsBuilder$AjcClosure1.run(MedicationsBuilder.java:1) [CentricityPractice.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3495]
    at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149) [aspectjrt-1.8.9.jar:]
    at com.gehcit.cp.aop.monitor.MonitoredAspect.run(MonitoredAspect.java:36) [CentricityPracticeCore.jar:]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cda.builder.MedicationsBuilder.buildSection(MedicationsBuilder.java:157) [CentricityPractice.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3495]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cda.builder.MedicationsBuilder.buildSection(MedicationsBuilder.java:93) [CentricityPractice.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3495]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cda.builder.AbstractDocumentBuilder.createSections(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:72) [CentricityPractice.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3495]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cda.builder.ContinuityOfCareDocumentBuilder.buildDocument_aroundBody0(ContinuityOfCareDocumentBuilder.java:71) [CentricityPractice.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3495]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cda.builder.ContinuityOfCareDocumentBuilder$AjcClosure1.run(ContinuityOfCareDocumentBuilder.java:1) [CentricityPractice.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3495]
    at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149) [aspectjrt-1.8.9.jar:]
    at com.gehcit.cp.aop.monitor.MonitoredAspect.run(MonitoredAspect.java:36) [CentricityPracticeCore.jar:]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cda.builder.ContinuityOfCareDocumentBuilder.buildDocument(ContinuityOfCareDocumentBuilder.java:63) [CentricityPractice.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3495]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cda.builder.ContinuityOfCareDocumentBuilder.buildDocument(ContinuityOfCareDocumentBuilder.java:22) [CentricityPractice.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3495]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cda.service.impl.ClinicalDocumentServiceImpl.buildDocument(ClinicalDocumentServiceImpl.java:512) [CentricityPractice.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3495]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cda.service.impl.ClinicalDocumentServiceImpl.getClinicalDocument_aroundBody12(ClinicalDocumentServiceImpl.java:177) [CentricityPractice.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3495]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cda.service.impl.ClinicalDocumentServiceImpl$AjcClosure13.run(ClinicalDocumentServiceImpl.java:1) [CentricityPractice.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3495]
    at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149) [aspectjrt-1.8.9.jar:]
    at com.gehcit.cp.aop.monitor.MonitoredClassAspect.run(MonitoredClassAspect.java:53) [CentricityPracticeCore.jar:]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cda.service.impl.ClinicalDocumentServiceImpl.getClinicalDocument_aroundBody14(ClinicalDocumentServiceImpl.java:159) [CentricityPractice.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3495]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cda.service.impl.ClinicalDocumentServiceImpl$AjcClosure15.run(ClinicalDocumentServiceImpl.java:1) [CentricityPractice.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3495]
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:66) [spring-aspects-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:72) [spring-aspects-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) [spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:70) [spring-aspects-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cda.service.impl.ClinicalDocumentServiceImpl.getClinicalDocument(ClinicalDocumentServiceImpl.java:159) [CentricityPractice.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3495]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cda.service.impl.ClinicalDocumentServiceImpl.getClinicalDocumentAsByteArray_aroundBody16(ClinicalDocumentServiceImpl.java:280) [CentricityPractice.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3495]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cda.service.impl.ClinicalDocumentServiceImpl$AjcClosure17.run(ClinicalDocumentServiceImpl.java:1) [CentricityPractice.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3495]
    at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149) [aspectjrt-1.8.9.jar:]
    at com.gehcit.cp.aop.monitor.MonitoredClassAspect.run(MonitoredClassAspect.java:53) [CentricityPracticeCore.jar:]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cda.service.impl.ClinicalDocumentServiceImpl.getClinicalDocumentAsByteArray(ClinicalDocumentServiceImpl.java:189) [CentricityPractice.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3495]
    at com.gehcit.cp.cem.payloadgenerator.CcdaCcdPayloadGenerator.createCCD(CcdaCcdPayloadGenerator.java:123) [CommonEventModel.jar:EMR_9.12SP3_Hotfix2_CI_9.12.3.3461]
    ... 53 more
```

Comment: Apparently you have a many-to-one association with `FetchType.LAZY` that refers to an entity that doesn't exist. Add a foreign key constraint to your tables to avoid this.

Comment: I have all fetchType.eager every where in the code

Comment: Even if you have that, lazy loading might be triggered due to the possible circularity. In the end this process then runs into a missing object for a FK value.

Comment: Can you explain this further ? I have the same problem and run into a stack overflow error after those logging messages. I mean there will always be circularity wount there ? Those 2 entities are referencing eachother... every entity A with a collection of entity B ( which in turn references collections of entity A) will potentially be endless -  they keep referencing eachother ad infinitum. I wonder how this would look in a debugging session anyway. But i cant get the many to many relation with hibernate to work to save my life....

Comment: @MajesticOl We could not crack this so moved to SQL query instead of using HQL.